# Must be presented and must be existed

Tags: grammaticality

This feature **must be existed** in all products.

This feature **must be presented** in all products.

vs

This feature **must exist** in all products.

This feature **must present** in all products.

Which are grammatical?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> This feature must be existed in all products.

This is ungrammatical. *Exist* is an intransitive verb—it does not take a Direct Object—and therefore it cannot be cast into the passive.

> This feature must be presented in all products.

This is grammatical, but not idiomatic. To *present* something is to “cause it to be (a) present”, in the sense of either exhibiting it or making a gift of it. We say that

- a play is *presented* by a  theatre company — the company exhibits the play to an audience
- an award is *presented* to a winner — an organization gives the award to the winner

We do say that a product *presents* certain features, but this implies a bit more than just the presence or existence of the features: it implies that features of interest are made available to users.

> This feature must exist in all products.

This is both grammatical and acceptably idiomatic, but it is not the best way to say what I think you have in mind—see below the line.

> This feature must present in all products.

This is not idiomatic. Intransitive *present* means to ‘make oneself present’ to some interested party; it is used almost exlusively of medical patients who “present” with symptoms for a physician to diagnose.

---

The ordinary way of saying what you seem to be driving at does not use either the verb *exist* or the verb *present* but the adjective *present*:

> This feature must be present in all products.

Note that the noun *present* (meaning either the current time or a gift) and the adjective *present* (meaning existing at the current location in time and space) have the stress on the first syllable, while the verb *present* has the stress on the second syllable.

Comment: Just to quibble: "The feature must be presented in all products" would be grammatically correct and idiomatic if what you meant to say was that the feature must be highlighted or made to stand out in all products. Like you might say, "The company logo must be presented on the front cover of all products". But that doesn't appear to be what the OP is trying to say, so I mention it only as an aside.

Comment: @Jay I **love** quibbles and I acknowledge the validity of this one.